# Populating an rdlc report from a number of tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I have a RDLC report which shows a table of rows each representing a timesheet entry from an employee for a specific client, such as:

> ```
> Date      Client    Employee  |Work Type |Hours Rate Total Total Invoiced Profit
> 2012-01-20|Client A|Employee 1|Project A |3.00|30.00|90.00|120.00        |30.00
>
> 2012-02-20|Client A|Employee 2|Project B |2.00|40.00|80.00|100.00        |20.00
>
> ....................................................................
>
> Totals Client A                           5.00|70.00|170.00|220.00       |50.00
>
> Company annual Fee 2012                              150.00
>
> Total PL                                             200.00
> ```

The data for the above table come from two different tables, Timesheet Entries table holding hours entered for each Client, and InvoiceEntries table holding invoice amounts for the Client. The DataTable for the data is populated by running a query JOINing the two tables, and returning a table such as:

> ```
> Date|Employee|Client|Hours Worked|Rate|Total|Invoiced Amount|Annual Fees
> ```

Now since Annual Fees was the same for all rows for the same Client, and because I want to group the data rows by Client and have totals at the bottom in the report, I programmatically in the code behind created a new DataTable which I populate using the data from the Datatable I get from the DB query by running a loop throuh its rows, but I manipulate the AnnualFees field to have a value only when I change Company, else I set it to zero. Thus I ensure that the annual fees field for each Client is only populated once, so that when I calculate the totals fields at the bottom of the report table I get the correct value.

This has worked well so good, but now the users requested that when the report is ran, if there are Annual fees for 2013 (so that the report period covers two years, or more), the would like to have them listed individually after each Client's timesheet entries totals.

Clearly I can no longer use an extra field in the data table, as the number of years for which annual fees exist is unknown.

Does anyone have an idea I can implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue; For future reference, here is what I did:
I added a new field called RowType in my datatable. 
In code-behind, I make two database calls, one to retrieve the timesheet entries and a second to retrieve the annual fees for each company. Using them, I build the datatable used to bind the report onto. The rows containing Timesheet entries have the RowType field equal to "Project Fees", whereas the rows containing annual fees have it set to "Annual Fees".

I then created an additional RowGroup on the report, based on the new field, and set its visibility and sorting parameters accordingly to show/ not show when the RowType has one value or the other.

This seems to be working.